# N+1 queens algorithm

Tags: algorithm, enumeration, backtracking, brute-force, n-queens

I'm looking to improve the speed of my algorithm to calculate the number of solutions to the N+1 queens problem (place `N+1` queens on a `NxN` chessboard with 1 pawn).
I'm basically using brute-force combined with backtracking, I first place a pawn on a random location on the board (without the edges and corners of the square without edges) and after that I just start to place queens using backtracking. This method is easy, but also slow. What algorithms would be faster?

I was thinking of first placing a pawn and 4 queens on each side of the pawn, but I'm not sure that it would improve the calculation speed.

Comment: Have you considered formulating it as a constraint problem and solving it using a standard CP solver?

Comment: This is a problem which calls more for a paper, pen and logic than brutal force.

Comment: This isn't a good answer in itself, but there are a lot of optimisations described on the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle) for this problem.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem. Do you want the queens not attacking each other or all the queens not attacking the pawn?

Comment: The 8 queens problems is not the same as the one I'm trying to solve..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are looking to count **all** the solutions of the problem, placing the pawn first on a random position will not do. You will have to place the pawn on **each position**. I believe the best algorithm here is backtracking, but still you can do some optimizations. In the n-queen problem an improtant bit is to take advantage of the symmetry of solutions, so I guess you can do this here as well. Having a solution, all of its 4 rotatations and their mirror images are also solutions.

Comment: Just wanted to write the same. Using the rotations, he can reduce the possibilities by a factor of 4 immediately.

Comment: factor of 8 in fact, you can also mirror in the diagonals.

Answer (score 0):

Your own suggestion sounds correct as it starts with the basic constraint that any solution needs to satisfy, rather than verifying that after the fact for each candidate solution.

For exhaustive search problems, the biggest speedoff usually comes when you implement an **early exit** rule: as soon as one queen attacks another, you do not place any more queens, and proceed to a new square for the last queen. This will greatly reduce the search space compared to the exhaustive search where you only check mutually attacks when all pieces have been placed on the board.

The pawn position on an `NxN` board can be reduced to the inner `(N-2)x(N-2)` subboard, and you can use the 8-fold rotation/mirror symmetry to reduce that even further to one of the octants of that inner square.